# TestFlight does not accept my release-IPA for FlightPath. Reason for concern?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, testflight, flightpath

So I did what many suggested and kept TestFlight SDK in the release build to be prepared when FlightPath finally launches.

However: After following TestFlight's [instructions](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829571-does-the-sdk-support-production-builds-) for the predecessor called "TestFlight Live", TestFlight refuses to accept my App Store IPA *(continue reading)* and gives this message:

> Invalid IPA: The keychain-access-group in the embedded.mobileprovision
>   and your binary don't match.

I did what they said:

1) Made a release build and submitted to the App Store, with TestFlight SDK and checkpoint calls included, but -setDeviceIdentifier: call removed.

2) From Xcode Organizer window: Selected the submitted archive, clicked "Distribute" to re-structure it as a TestFlight-compatible binary, signed for AdHoc distribution over TestFlight.

Apparently this binary is garbage for TestFlight which lefts me wondering: How am I supposed to ever get to the analytics data once FlightPath arrives? Am I better off rejecting my submission and stripping out all the useless TestFlight SDK code or can this be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to upload the app store build of your app for it to work with flight path. As long as you have uploaded or created an app that has the same bundle id and app token the app will appear in flightpath without you having to upload.

Make sure you have the correct app token that matches your bundle id!

Comment: Where did they mention that the bundle id must match the app token? TestFlight auto-generated the app token for one of my builds when I decided to include the TestFlight SDK.

Comment: Each app on your team has a unique bundle id. If you change the bundle id for your production version, a new app must be created with a new app token. That sometimes happens to people. I just wanted to be really clear.